# What kind of Canon battery grip is this?

Tags: canon, canon-50d, battery-grip

I just spotted this battery grip, and apparently it's attached to a Canon EOS 50D camera. But what kind of battery grip is this? It has a small LCD display in the upper left corner, as seen from the back of the camera. It also features two status indicator LEDs, one labeled "USB" and the other "LAN". Amazingly it also features an AF-ON button.

Does anyone recognize this battery grip? Is it a Canon original or a clone? What model is it?

[image]

Found [here](http://www.kenrockwell.com/canon/50d.htm).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a [Canon WFT-E3A Wireless Transmitter Grip](http://www.globalmediapro.com/dp/A29D45/Canon-WFT-E3A-Wireless-File-Transmitter/) for the 40D and 50D...

It allows you to upload photos immediately to a computer or other storage device, as you're shooting.

Comment: Oh! It's one of those fancy things! Alright, thank you!